# Unable to move the cache access is denied. (0x5) python

Tags: python, shell, caching, cmd, purge

I am having issues with running simple python script (just printing "hello").

I don't know what I have done because I was able to run scripts on shell but for the moment, the same error is happening again and again and I don't have any solutions.
Someone has an idea ?

```
[13568:1130/110807.054:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(20)] Unable to move the cache: AccÞs refusÚ. (0x5)
[13568:1130/110807.054:ERROR:cache_util.cc(145)] Unable to move cache folder C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache\Cache_Data to C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Code\Cache\old_Cache_Data_000
[13568:1130/110807.054:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(196)] Unable to create cache
```

I have try to delete the cache but nothing happened. I think it change after running pip cache purge.

I have also try to desinstall vsc and reinstall but it's the same.